# How can I find what MyNamespace is for GetManifestResourceStream?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a XML called british-english-dictionary.xml loaded in my Solution Explorer. It is set as an Embedded Resource under the Build Action.

I'm trying to read it using the following code:

```
Dim asm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
Dim var = asm.GetManifestResourceStream("MyNamespace.british-english-dictionary.xml")
```

The problem is that it isn't loading; I believe it is because the MyNamespace part it incorrect, but how do I find out what the MyNamespace should be replaced with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The important setting is Project + Properties, Application tab, Default namespace.  That's the name that prefixes the name of the file.

You can always double-check the actual name as used in the assembly manifest by using Ildasm.exe.  Double-click the Manifest in the main window and locate the .mresource statement.  A sample program I created with the default namespace set to "Foo" and test.xml added as an embedded resource produced this output in Ildasm.exe:

```
.mresource public Foo.test.xml
{
  // Offset: 0x00000000 Length: 0x00000011
}
```

Comment: I've tried as you suggested and in the settings the root namespace is listed as "WindowsApplication2". I've tried ammending it with this but still no luck? `Dim var = asm.GetManifestResourceStream("WindowsApplication2.british-english-dictionary.xml")`

Comment: So what did ildasm.exe tell you?  Run it from the Visual Studio Command Prompt.

Comment: I tried ildasm.exe on the published exe file but it failed with error "C\Users\Andy\Documents\setup.exe has no valid CLR header and cannot be disassembled

Comment: Yah, don't run that on your installer.  Run it on the assembly that the compiler created.  WindowsApplication2.exe by the sound of it.

Comment: `'.mresource public 'WindowsApplication2.british-english-dictionary.xml'
{
  // Offset: 0x00000000 Length: 0x01E038D9
}'`

I got the following from that. Does this confirm that the resource is loaded into my program correctly and that the name reference I was using to try and call it is also correct?

Comment: It confirms that using "MyNamespace" was wrong.  It doesn't otherwise confirm that GetExecutingAssembly() was the correct assembly reference to use without using the debugger.

Comment: Thank you Hans, my program is still broken and won't load the xml file, but at least I can rule this out!